# oramds unknown protocol error

Tags: business-process-management

i have below given code to get data from bpm engine but came across an error as mentioned below. Can someone tell me some working code or help me to resolve the issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.FabricConfigManager.getMetadataManager(FabricConfigManager.java:205)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.FabricConfigManager.loadConfigObject(FabricConfigManager.java:620)
    at oracle.tip.pc.services.identity.config.ISConfiguration.init(ISConfiguration.java:170)
    at oracle.tip.pc.services.identity.config.ISConfiguration.<clinit>(ISConfiguration.java:130)
    at bpm.BpmTester.main(BpmTester.java:52)
Caused by: oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: oramds: unknown protocol: oramds: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: oramds: unknown protocol: oramds
    at oracle.fabric.common.FabricMetadataManagerFactory.createMetadataManager(FabricMetadataManagerFactory.java:217)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.FabricConfigManager$MDMHolder.<clinit>(FabricConfigManager.java:200)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: oracle.fabric.common.FabricException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: oramds: unknown protocol: oramds
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.MDSMetadataManagerImpl.<init>(MDSMetadataManagerImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at oracle.fabric.common.FabricMetadataManagerFactory.createMetadataManager(FabricMetadataManagerFactory.java:213)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: oramds
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at oracle.integration.platform.common.MDSMetadataManagerImpl.<init>(MDSMetadataManagerImpl.java:138)
    ... 13 more
```

JavaCode::

```
IWorkflowServiceClient wfSvcClient;
            try{

             Map properties = new HashMap<IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY, String>();
             properties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.SOAP_END_POINT_ROOT, "http://hostname:port");
             properties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.SECURITY_POLICY_URI, "oracle/wss10_saml_token_client_policy"); 
             properties.put(IWorkflowServiceClientConstants.CONNECTION_PROPERTY.MANAGEMENT_POLICY_URI, "oracle/log_policy");


        wfSvcClient=WorkflowServiceClientFactory.getWorkflowServiceClient(WorkflowServiceClientFactory.SOAP_CLIENT,properties,null);

        IWorkflowContext wfCtx=wfSvcClient.getTaskQueryService().authenticate(userId, password.toCharArray(),oracle.tip.pc.services.identity.config.ISConfiguration.getDefaultRealmName() 
            );
            IWorkflowContext adminCtx = wfSvcClient.getTaskQueryService().authenticate(adminUserId, pwd, 
                                            oracle.tip.pc.services.identity.config.ISConfiguration.getDefaultRealmName(),
                                             userId);
            ITaskQueryService querySvc=wfSvcClient.getTaskQueryService();
            Predicate.enableXMLSerialization(true);
            // Build the predicate
               Predicate statePredicate = new Predicate(TableConstants.WFTASK_STATE_COLUMN,
                                            Predicate.OP_NEQ,
                                            IWorkflowConstants.TASK_STATE_ASSIGNED);
                    statePredicate.addClause(Predicate.AND,
                                     TableConstants.WFTASK_NUMBERATTRIBUTE1_COLUMN,
                                     Predicate.OP_IS_NULL,
                                     nullParam);
               Predicate datePredicate = new Predicate(TableConstants.WFTASK_ENDDATE_COLUMN,
                                            Predicate.OP_ON,
                                            new Date());
               Predicate predicate = new Predicate(statePredicate, Predicate.AND, datePredicate);

               // Create the ordering
               Ordering ordering = new Ordering(TableConstants.WFTASK_TITLE_COLUMN, true, true);        
                 ordering.addClause(TableConstants.WFTASK_PRIORITY_COLUMN, true, true);

               // List of display columns
               // For those columns that are not specified here, the queried Task object will not hold any value.
               // For example: If TITLE is not specified, task.getTitle() will return null
               // For the list of most comonly used columns, check the table below
               // Note: TASKID is fetched by default. So there is no need to explicitly specity it.
               List queryColumns = new ArrayList();
                 queryColumns.add("TASKNUMBER");     
                 queryColumns.add("TITLE");
                 queryColumns.add("PRIORITY");
                 queryColumns.add("STATE");
                 queryColumns.add("ENDDATE");
                 queryColumns.add("NUMBERATTRIBUTE1");
                 queryColumns.add("TEXTATTRIBUTE1");

               // List of optional info
               // Any optionalInfo specified can be fetched from the Task object
               // For example: if you have specified "CustomActions", you can retrieve
               // it using task.getSystemAttributes().getCustomActions();
               // "Actions" (All Actions) - task.getSystemAttributes().getSystemActions()
               // "GroupActions" (Only group Actions: Actions that can be permoded by the user as a member of a group)
               //                - task.getSystemAttributes().getSystemActions()
               // "ShortHistory" - task`enter code here`.getSystemAttributes().getShortHistory()
               List optionalInfo = new ArrayList();
                 optionalInfo.add("Actions");
                 //optionalInfo.add("GroupActions");
                 //optionalInfo.add("CustomActions");
                 //optionalInfo.add("ShortHistory");
                 // The following is reserved for future use. 
                 // If you need them, please use getTaskDetailsById (or) getTaskDetailsByNumber,
                 // which will fetch all information related to a task, which includes these
                    //optionalInfo.add("Attachments");
                    //optionalInfo.add("Comments");
                    //optionalInfo.add("Payload");

               List tasksList = querySvc.queryTasks(wfCtx,
                                           queryColumns,
                                           optionalInfo,
                                           ITaskQueryService.ASSIGNMENT_FILTER_MY_AND_GROUP,
                                           keyword,
                                           predicate, 
                                           ordering, 
                                           0,0); // No Paging

               // How to use paging:
               // 1. If you need to dynamically calculate paging size (or) to display/find 
               //    out the number of pages, the user has to scroll (Like page X of Y)
               //      Call queryTasks to find out the number of tasks it returns. Using this 
               //      calculate your paging size (The number of taks you want in a page)
               //      Call queryTasks successively varing the startRow and endRow params.  
               //      For example: If the total number of tasks is 30 and your want a paging size
               //      of 10, you can call with (startRow, endRow): (1, 10) (11, 20) (21, 30) 
               // 2. If you have fixed paging size, just keep calling queryTasks successively with 
               //      the paging size (If your paging size is 10, you can call with (startRow, endRow): 
               //      (1, 10) (11, 20) (21, 30) (31, 40).....  until the number of tasks returned is 
               //      less than your paging size (or) there are no more tasks returned     

               if (tasksList != null) { // There are tasks 
                 System.out.println("Total number of tasks: " + tasksList.size()); 
                 System.out.println("Tasks List: ");
                 Task task = null; 
                 for (int i = 0; i < tasksList.size(); i++) { 
                   task = (Task) tasksList.get(i);          
                   System.out.println("Task Number: " + task.getSystemAttributes().getTaskNumber());
                   System.out.println("Task Id: " + task.getSystemAttributes().getTaskId());
                   System.out.println("Title: " + task.getTitle());
                   System.out.println("Priority: " + task.getPriority());
                   System.out.println("State: " + task.getSystemAttributes().getState());
                   System.out.println();
                   // Retrive any Optional Info specified
                   // Use task service, to perform operations on the task
                 }
               }
        }
        catch(WorkflowException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        catch(BPMConfigException e){
            System.out.print("hello");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

oramds is a oracle soa specific thing, are you developing a client that runs outside of the soa suite? then you ll have to get the referenced wsdl/xsd and make sure they look ok in some other tool like eclipse or soapui